# Stop Lightbox2 gallery on {display: none;} images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently using [Lightbox2](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/) by Lokesh Dakhar to display a gallery of product images on an online catalogue website.

**Example:**

```
[Yellow Banana] [Red Apple] [Yellow Lemon]     ← Image Gallary
```

I am also using a client-side search filter (to narrow down results to specific information) that hides product images by attaching the css rule `display: none` if the data input does not match the name of the product.

**Example:**

```
Search: Yellow
```

**Result:**

```
[Yellow Banana] [Yellow Lemon]
```

My **Problem** is that the Lightbox2 gallary is still showing the `[Red Apple]` in between these two products on Lightbox's "next image".

Is there a way to attach an `if` statement to the Lightbox script making it ignore products that have `display: none` currently attached to them?

Reproduced Problem in: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/BobaMilkTease/21orz43n/) with documentation.

Comment: Your example is javascript not jquery

Comment: @Zl3n Lightbox is a jQuery plugin and actually uses jQuery. The tag is relevant, imo.

Comment: @CronosS exact. Sorry. But I can't help him, I dont know pure Javascript...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a version of your `input` event handler which will do the trick.

```
document.getElementById("search").addEventListener("input", function() {
  var filter = this.value,
    pictures = $(".searchable");

  pictures.each(function() {
    if (this.dataset.index.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
      $(this).show().find("a").attr("data-lightbox", "roadtrip");
    } else {
      $(this).hide().find("a").attr("data-lightbox", "ignore");
    }
  });
});
```

This code uses jQuery to hide / show filtered elements rather than setting an in-page style tag.

**Lightbox** treats images as a group when they have the same `data-lightbox` attribute. To exclude an image from the group, simply change this attribute (*ignore*, in my example).

Comment: Worked! Thank you, however it seems to have added another little bug. While searching for the item, if you make an accidental typo `16FF` and delete the typo (in this case the additional "F") the items do not re appear unless you clear the input box & re-type the `16F` correctly. It's not a huge problem, but if you know a fix that would be much appreciated! Updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/BobaMilkTease/21orz43n/5/)

Comment: @Ghost Thanks for the feedback. Answer edited with the new js code.